# How to read template file in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  nginx.ingress.tmpl: {{ (tpl (.Files.Get "nginx.ingress.tmpl") . | quote ) }}
```

How do you read template file in helm?

I get error

> at <tpl (.Files.Get "nginx.ingress.tmpl") .>: error calling tpl: error during tpl function execution for "# configuration for

Comment: Should `nginx.ingress.tmpl` file be rendered or it is just a static file and should be included?

Comment: Could you include content of `nginx.ingress.tmpl` since this `helm` configuration seem to work with my test bench on `minikube`.

Comment: Something is written incorrectly in the *nginx.ingress.tmpl* file.

Comment: It should be rendered because it looks like


# configuration for {{.Ingress.Namespace}}/{{.Ingress.Name}}
{{range $upstream := .Upstreams}}
upstream {{$upstream.Name}} {
        {{if ne $upstream.UpstreamZoneSize "0"}}zone {{$upstream.Name}} {{$upstream.UpstreamZoneSize}};{{end}}
        {{if $upstream.LBMethod }}{{$upstream.LBMethod}};{{end}}
        {{range $server := $upstream.UpstreamServers}}
        server {{$server.Address}}:{{$server.Port}} max_fails={{$server.MaxFails}}

Comment: Add It in the Question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "nginx.ingress.tmpl" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
        {{ $files.Get . }}
  {{- end }}
```

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/

Comment: Where should `tpl` get invoked?

Comment: It works; I tested the template using *helm template* command and the build was created successfully

Comment: I get error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 10: could not find expected ':'